# what is the <% in the php files and how it should compile?

Tags: php, reference

I have new sample.php file that is it active on a cpanel (Apache server) and it is work correctly on that cpanel, I don't know how it is working! because it is PHP file but it is using `<%` instead of `<?PHP` in it's php syntax and `%>` instead of `?>` and `<%=` instead of `<?PHP echo`.
can you tell me what is the <% and how I can enable it in my cpanel?

Comment: Are you running this server under IIS? The "<%" tags are very likely being parsed via IIS.

Comment: There's a setting called `asp_tags` in [php.ini](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) that will allow you to use ASP style tags.  Warning, it's going to disappear in later versions op php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<%` are called "asp-style tags".

If you have access to the php.ini, set `asp_tags = Off` or `asp_tags = 0` to `asp_tags = On` or `asp_tags = 1` respectively.

To temporarily enable asp-tags for a script, you can add `<?php ini_set('asp_tags',1) ?>` to the beginning of the file, but this is less than ideal.

The alternative would be to replace each `<%` with `<?php` and each `%>` with `?>`. If you are using short_tags, you can replace `<%`, `%>,` and `<%=` with `<?`, `?>`, and `<?=`, respectively.

Comment: More info about php tags on http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php